# app using altbeacon not showing distance

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

i am trying to create and app to locate beacon and get its distance and i am using altbeacon library for that. by using the code i get details of nearby beacon but i didn't get the distance. here is my code and stacktrace. what is the problem in my code can anyone please help me to identify.

MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer{


    public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

        beaconManager.bind(this);
   }


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        final Region region = new Region("myBeaons", null, null, null);

        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");        
                }
            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region arg1) {

                for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





}
```

manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.beaconexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:isolatedProcess="false"
            android:label="beacon" />
        <service
            android:name="org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

and stacktrace

```
  08-04 06:33:32.344: V/Monotype(10057): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.beaconexample
08-04 06:33:32.348: V/Monotype(10057):     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
08-04 06:33:32.354: V/Monotype(10057): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.beaconexample
08-04 06:33:32.354: V/Monotype(10057):     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
08-04 06:33:32.396: I/BeaconManager(10057): BeaconManager started up on pid 10057 named 'com.example.beaconexample' for application package 'com.example.beaconexample'.  isMainProcess=true
08-04 06:33:32.399: D/BeaconParser(10057): Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
08-04 06:33:32.408: D/OpenGLRenderer(10057): Render dirty regions requested: true
08-04 06:33:32.413: D/Atlas(10057): Validating map...
08-04 06:33:32.421: I/CycledLeScanner(10057): This Android 5.0.  We are using new scanning APIs
08-04 06:33:32.434: I/BeaconService(10057): beaconService version 2.11 is starting up on the main process
08-04 06:33:32.437: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(10057): App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
08-04 06:33:32.459: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(10057): Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
08-04 06:33:32.459: W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator(10057): Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
08-04 06:33:32.463: I/BeaconService(10057): binding
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C1.05.00.02.087.140_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C1.05.00.02.087.140__release_AU (I6eddbfa548)
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.02
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): Build Date: 09/17/15 Thu
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): Local Branch: 
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C1.05.00.02.087.140
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): Local Patches: NONE
08-04 06:33:32.472: I/Adreno-EGL(10057): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
08-04 06:33:32.475: I/OpenGLRenderer(10057): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-04 06:33:32.487: D/OpenGLRenderer(10057): Enabling debug mode 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): PartialUpdate status: Disabled
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Left Align: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Width Align: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Top Align: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Height Align: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Min ROI Width: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Min ROI Height: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Needs ROI Merge: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Dynamic Fps: Disabled
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Min Panel fps: 0
08-04 06:33:32.489: I/qdutils(10057): Max Panel fps: 0
08-04 06:33:32.534: I/BeaconService(10057): start ranging received
08-04 06:33:32.564: D/BluetoothLeScanner(10057): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
08-04 06:33:32.564: I/Timeline(10057): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1fc91e75 time:12888793
08-04 06:33:32.695: D/BluetoothLeScanner(10057): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=00:A0:50:B2:95:AD, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, -14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=TCZ], mRssi=-76, mTimestampNanos=47409899203234}
08-04 06:33:33.340: D/BluetoothLeScanner(10057): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=00:A0:50:B2:94:9B, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, -14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=TCZ], mRssi=-84, mTimestampNanos=47410545673859}
```

Comment: You say "I didn't get the distance".  What does this mean?  What does it print for distance?

Comment: i mean to say none of the function setRangeNotifier and addRangeNotifier called and does not print following logs
    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
     Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");

Answer (score 1):

```
private double calculateDistance(int rssi){
        int txPower = -59; //hard coded power value. Usually ranges between -59 to -65

        if (rssi == 0) {
            return -1.0;
        }

        double ratio = rssi * 1.0 / txPower;

        if (ratio < 1.0) {
            return Math.pow(ratio,10);
        }else{
            return (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;
        }

    }
```

use this code to calculate beacon distance bcoz most of the beacon has different TxPower. you have to Calibrate beacon to get TxPower

-59 TxPower you will get by default

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the issue is that no beacons are detected and `didRangeBeaconsInRegion(...)` is never called.

Try changing:
                        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

To use a different layout expression, perhaps the one for iBeacon if that is what you are trying to detect.  You can find a list of expressions for different beacon formats here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com

Comment: Thanks for reply i can change beaconLayout and code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

hi david my code detects all beacons and shows following details in logcat

```
    08-04 06:33:32.695: D/BluetoothLeScanner(10057): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=00:A0:50:B2:95:AD, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, -14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=TCZ], mRssi=-76, mTimestampNanos=47409899203234}
08-04 06:33:33.340: D/BluetoothLeScanner(10057): onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=00:A0:50:B2:94:9B, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[0, -14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=TCZ], mRssi=-84, mTimestampNanos=47410545673859}
```

but following code is not working

```
 @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        final Region region = new Region("myBeaons", null, null, null);

        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");        
                }
            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region arg1) {

                for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and my main task is to get distance of the beacon device.